# How to set up environment after installation of a software inside home directory?

Tags: software-installation, path, profile

I am not familiar much with environment and path settings in UNIX environment. I have installed CDO (climate data operators) in a folder in my home directory. I am only able to run it when I go into `/home/name/cdo/src`. How should I set up any of the dotfiles to access it in home directory without specifically going into src folder?

Comment: You should read up about the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Thanks. I had to figure out what type of shell I am using then I simply added executable path to ./path file.